# Recursive sizeof in gdb?

Tags: c++, gdb

Is there a way using gdb, or perhaps another tool, to find a total size of some struct/class including memory pointed to by all accessible pointer members?  There is a basic sizeof, however this doesn't account for the size of members which are pointers, only the pointer size itself.  So, perhaps more clearly, what I want is a sizeof operation which will add the sizeof a pointer member and the  sizeof the memory pointed to by said pointer for each pointer member (and so on for further nesting).

I am okay with approximations, absolute precision is unnecessary.

I would prefer a solution which supports c++, however a solution which works with c is better than nothing.  Though, I imagine most solutions will probably work with both,  assuming a solution exists.

Hopefully that description makes sense, I appreciate any advice on how to accomplish this task, thanks.

Comment: You'd have to write this specific for your class... sizeof() only counts "the pointer size itself" because that's all that contributes to the size.

Comment: This is true within the context of the language, but I was hoping external debuggers may be able to go a step beyond. Or if gdb can't maybe another tool can.

Comment: If a pointer member points to the first element of an array (which is a common idiom), how would you determine how many elements of that array to count? What if a struct contains a pointer to itself, which is *very* common; the potential size would be infinite.

Comment: @Keith this is true, however, it wouldn't be impossible for a debugger to bail on circular dependencies. And maybe it can't  everything perfect, but any level of recursive size gets you closer at least.

Comment: Adding to @Keith's, and to counter your response: Also, are some of the pointer-members duplicates, thus do not count extra? Are some of the non-pointers handles for an arbitrary amount of extra-data? Are some of the pointers non-owning, and thus do not contribute extra? There are many more scenarios, and you as the developer are the only one who could possibly know.

Comment: @deduplicator The problem is programmers don't program everything.   We use libraries, and other code written by others.  And sometimes you don't have full documentation to the internals.  I think the safest way to do things would be don't count duplicates, which should be fairly sane, and count non owning data since it's data used regardless if it's shared or not.   Either way some metric is better than no metric.

Comment: In that case you obviously failed to understand that the neccessary information, even for that bad way to estimate things, is probably not in your program. That was what both Keith and I were getting at.

Comment: "*... but any level of recursive size gets you closer at least*." Closer to what exactly? I suggest you update your question to clarify what you're looking for. It may be something like "the sum of the sizes of the object in question and of any objects recursively reachable via any pointer members" (I don't claim that's the best possible wording). That's not what I'd call the "true size" of anything, but it's reasonably unambiguous, and perhaps someone can figure out how to compute it in gdb. Presumably it would not attempt to follow null pointers. Pointers to array elements are still tricky.

Comment: @keith correct. I'll think of a way to phase things better and update accordingly. Arrays may not work with that method, but at least general pointers would which is an improvement still.

Comment: This looks like an XY problem. Why do you need such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way to do this in gdb.  I also do not know of another pre-canned tool for doing this.

However, I think it would be pretty easy to write for gdb, using the Python scripting ability.  At least, this is true if you are using "regular" data structures.  In some cases it isn't possible to do this with the information readily available to gdb.  For example, if you have a struct containing a "void *", there's no way to know what it points to using just the debuginfo.  Also sometimes classes can be written in an obscure style that prevents automated discovery -- there are a couple of classes in libstdc++ like this.

If you want to go even further you could maybe adapt the gdb-heap project, which might let you dig up information about the "void *" case and others.

Comment: It's not just `void*` that's a problem -- read the comments, particularly Keith's "If a pointer member points to the first element of an array (which is a common idiom), how would you determine how many elements of that array to count?"